# Find nearest whole integer(s) on function

Tags: functions, integers

I have two functions as follows:

$$a=\frac{5}{16}(x+2y)$$
$$b=-\frac{5}{16}(x-2y)$$

The user may enter any arbitrary number for *(x, y)*. However only values which produce whole integers of *a* and *b* are considered valid. Given these conditions, is it possible to find the nearest valid *(x, y)* to the user's inputted *x* and *y* which would produce whole numbers for *a* and *b*.

I thought representing both equations as planes and finding the closest point on them to a specified point using Lagrange multiplication. But wasn't sure exactly how to do so, to produce the results I was looking for.

Edit: Follow-up question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100966/find-closest-whole-integer-in-equation)

Comment: What do you mean by "nearest"?  Do you mean to find the valid $(x,y)$ whose Euclidean distance to the inputted $(x,y)$ is minimal?

Comment: @EricWofsey precisely that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

See, that $5$ and $16$ are relatively prime. So we need to
$$\begin{cases}x+2y \equiv 0 \mod 16\\
x-2y \equiv 0 \mod 16\end{cases}$$

We have then:
$$x+2y - (x-2y) \equiv 0 \mod 16$$
$$4y \equiv 0 \mod 16$$
So:
$$y\in \{16k, 16k+4, 16k+8, 16k+12 | k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Because $x+2y \equiv 0 \mod 16$, we have:

- for $y=16k$: $x\equiv 0 \mod 16$
- for $y=16k+4$: $x\equiv 8 \mod 16$
- for $y=16k+8$: $x\equiv 0 \mod 16$
- for $y=16k+12$: $x\equiv 8 \mod 16$

The valid pairs $(x,y)$ are then:
$$(x,y) \in \{(16l, 16k),(16l+8, 16k+4),(16l, 16k+8),(16l+8,16k+12)|l,k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Comment: Given the above functions for *a* and *b* in my question are simplified equations of the more generic equations:

$a=(py+qx)/(2pq)$ and 
$b=(py-qx)/(2pq)$

Where *p* and *q* represent some real number (in the above equations they're equal to 1.6 and 0.8, respectively).

Can your approach be used for these equations? And if so how?

Comment: @Manmax75 That would be good to ask as a new question and provide a link back to this one.